# How to show the accessoryType property of UITableViewCell only for one cell at a time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table view that I want to show a checkmark accessoryType only in the cell that is selected, but now what I have is a checkmark for every cell that was selected...can someone please help me to fix this method?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString * key = [self.settingsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString * key2 = [self.soundsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (tableView.tag != 313) {
        if([key isEqual:@"Reminder Sound"]){
            [self reminderSoundPressed];
        } else if([key isEqual:@"Sound"]){

        }
    }

    UITableViewCell *newCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    //setting the reminder
     if (tableView.tag == 313) {

         if ([key2 isEqual:@"Sound 1"]) {
             [self.delegate setReminderSound:@"reminderSound1.wav"];
             newCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

         }else if ([key2 isEqual:@"Sound 2"]) {
             [self.delegate setReminderSound:@"reminderSound2.wav"];
             newCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

         }else if ([key2 isEqual:@"Sound 3"]) {
             [self.delegate setReminderSound:@"reminderSound3.wav"];
             newCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
         }
     }
}
```

thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

When the user selects a row and you set the accessory type to `checkmark`, you have to loop through and change the accessory type for every other cell to `none`.

Answer (score 2):

A easy solution is to implement the delegate function 
[- tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:) and remove the checkbox there.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

A more elegant solution is to make a custom `UITableViewCell` class and override the setSelected function.

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected
           animated:(BOOL)animated
{
      [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
      self.accessoryType = selected ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone; 
}
```